# Regex - Not a match if there is a dash

Tags: regex

I have two kinds of strings.

index_12323 (just numbers, no dash).
index_12a-dcd-edff (basically an uuid).

What's a regex that only matches the first one, not the second one, basically, if it has dash, it is not a match.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something of this sort is what you're looking for:

```
^index_[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the "_" (underscore) is covered in the word character class, there is no need to explicitly check for it. Use this regex to match on the first pattern:

```
^\w+\d+$
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I probably didn't explain this well. I already tried things like index_\d+ . The thing I don't want it to do a partial match. If it is index_124ab-def, this will return index_124. I want it  to skip anything like that.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, my second regex would never match index_124 in  index_124ab-def because it matches from the start of the string to the end. have you tried it? What regex engine are you using?